# How can I loop through a directory and adjust file names

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, ksh

I want to write a ksh script that loops through a directory and changes the names of files to include a 001_DTS (where DTS is a date time stamp), 002_DTS, 003_DTS, etc

and remove the aa, ab, etc because I want to use this with the split function (the files created from that function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
prefix="x"   # the default 'split' prefix, change to suit yourself
count=1
dts=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

for f in "$prefix"[a-z][a-z]; do
  mv "$f" "$(printf "%s%03d_%s" "$prefix" $count $dts)"
  (( count++ ))
done
```

Comment: thanks very much! I assume the 'x' prefix is whatever I deem the file name prefix to be? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

how about this, not a shell specific (ksh/bash)

```
cd /path/to/dir
for file in *
 do 
  mv $file ${file}_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) && echo "file moved" || echo "unable to move"
done
```

If you want to fix the value of DTS before the loop just assign the variable like other posts.

Answer (score -2):

first, run bash :-) and then solve it:

```
bash # :-)
J=1
for I in * ; do
    mv -i $I `printf '%03d' $J`_DTS
    J=$((J+1))
done
```